# Android Kotlin View width set error "Val cannot be reassigned"

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin i am getting IDE error saying "**Val cannot be reassigned**" when i try to set width programmatically, Please see the code written in the onCreate() of Activity class,

```
shadowView.width = 200
```

Here **shadowView** is a View added in the layout

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply

```
shadowView.layoutParams.width = 200
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to set a view's width programmatically you should change its width in its layout params, like the example below:

```
val layoutParams = shadowView.layoutParams
layoutParams.width = 200
shadowView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```